# Gradient descent expression help

Tags: deep-learning, optimization, gradient-descent

In the section 2 of this [paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/7485-norm-matters-efficient-and-accurate-normalization-schemes-in-deep-networks.pdf). I didn't understand the following steps in the proof.

If $x$ is channel input, $w$ channel weight vector and $\hat{w} = w/$ $  ||w||_2$ then for batchnorm ($BN$) we have

$$BN(||w||_2 \hat{w}x)  = BN(\hat{w}x).$$

and

$$ \frac {\partial BN(||w||_2 \hat{w}x)}{\partial (||w||_2 \hat{w})} = \frac{1}{||w||_2} \frac{\partial BN(\hat{w}x)}{\partial (\hat{w})}$$

During training, the weights are typically incremented through some variant of stochastic gradient
descent, according to the gradient of the loss at mini-batch $t$, with learning rate $\eta$.

$$w_{t+1} = w_t - \eta \nabla L_t (w_t)$$.

Claim: During training, the weight direction $ \hat{w}_{t+1} = \frac {w_t}{||w_t||_2}$
is updated according to

$$\hat{w}_{t+1} = \hat{w}_t - \eta ||w_t||^{-2} (I - \hat{w}_t \hat{w}^T) \nabla L(\hat{w}_t) + O(\eta ^2)$$

I didn't understand how did the authors arrive at this step and I didn't understand the steps that followed it.